# searching if anyone of word is present in the another column of a dataframe or in another data frame using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

Hi I have two DataFrames like below

```
 DF1

 Alpha   |  Numeric  |  Special

 and     |  1        |   @
 or      |  2        |   $
         |  3        |   &  
         |  4        |     
         |  5        |
```

and

```
DF2 with single column

Content      |

boy or girl  |
school @ morn|
```

I want to search if anyone of the column in DF1 has anyone of the keyword in content column of DF2 and the output should be in a new DF

```
 output_DF

 output_column|
 Alpha        |
 Special      |
```

someone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

I have a method that is not very good.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[['and', 'or'],['1', '2','3','4','5'],['@', '$','&']]],columns=['Alpha','Numeric','Special'])    
print(df1)
       Alpha          Numeric    Special
0  [and, or]  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  [@, $, &]

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[['boy', 'or','girl']],[['school', '@','morn']]],columns=['Content'])    
print(df2)
             Content
0    [boy, or, girl]
1  [school, @, morn]
```

First, combine the df2 data：

```
df2list=[x for row in df2['Content'].tolist() for x in row]
print(df2list)
['boy', 'or', 'girl', 'school', '@', 'morn']
```

Then get data of each column of df1 is intersected with the df2list:

```
containlistname = []
for i in range(0,df1.shape[1]):
    columnsname = df1.columns[i]
    df1list=[x for row in df1[columnsname].tolist() for x in row]
    intersection = list(set(df1list).intersection(set(df2list)))
    if len(intersection)>0:
        containlistname.append(columnsname)
output_DF = pd.DataFrame(containlistname,columns=['output_column'])
```

Final print：

```
print(output_DF)
  output_column
0         Alpha
1       Special
```

Comment: I am getting "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable" in this line

      df1list=[x for row in df1[columnsname].tolist() for x in row]


Also I dont want to combine the df2 data, we need to find the match for each row (is it possible to itereate each row?)

Comment: The "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable" you get is that the number is in string format on my side.As for the question you mentioned later, I think you can only do the for cycle for each row. Sorry, I don't have a very good way to help you.

Comment: which number are you referring to ??, I changed the Numeric column values to string values but still I am facing the same error

Comment: I mean 1,2,3,4,5, there's float in you, and strings on my side

Comment: I changed the values to 'one','two','three','four','five' but still I am facing this issue

Comment: This code is correct in me. Do you use the df1 and df2 generated in the code?If so, I'm sorry  I don't know why it isn't correct in you.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply the `Series.isin()` method for each column in df1 and then return the column names for which there are any occurrences:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Alpha' :['and', 'or'],'Numeric':[1, 2,3,4,5],'Special':['@', '$','&']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict([ (k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in d.iteritems() ]))

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Content' :['boy or girl','school @ morn']})    

check = lambda r:[c for c in df1.columns if df1[c].dropna().isin(r).any()]
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'output_column' : df2["Content"].str.split(' ').apply(check)})
```

This results in:

```
  output_column
0       [Alpha]
1     [Special]
```