# How to get the count of occurence of a list of keywords on a datacolumn in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

```
 my_list=["one","is"]

 df
 Out[6]:
        Name    Story
   0    Kumar   Kumar is one of the great player in his team
   1    Ravi    Ravi is a good poet
   2    Ram     Ram drives well
```

if anyone of the items in my_list is present in the "Story" column I need to get the no of occurrence for all the items.

```
 my_desired_output

 new_df
 word     count
 one       1
 is        2
```

I achieved extracting the row which are having anyone of the items in my_list using

```
mask=df1["Story"].str.contains('|'.join(my_list),na=False) but now I am trying get the counts of each word in my_list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `Series` of words first:

```
a = df['Story'].str.split(expand=True).stack()
print (a)
0  0     Kumar
   1        is
   2       one
   3        of
   4       the
   5     great
   6    player
   7        in
   8       his
   9      team
1  0      Ravi
   1        is
   2         a
   3      good
   4      poet
2  0       Ram
   1    drives
   2      well
dtype: object
```

Then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html), get [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and for DataFrame add [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = a[a.isin(my_list)].value_counts().rename_axis('word').reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
  word  count
0   is      2
1  one      1
```

Another solution with creating list of all words by [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html), then fllaten by `from_iterable`, use `Counter` and last create `DataFrame` by constructor:

```
from collections import Counter
from  itertools import chain

my_list=["one","is"]

a = list(chain.from_iterable(df['Story'].str.split().values.tolist()))
print (a)
['Kumar', 'is', 'one', 'of', 'the', 'great', 'player', 
 'in', 'his', 'team', 'Ravi', 'is', 'a', 'good', 'poet', 'Ram', 'drives', 'well']

b = Counter([x for x in a if x in my_list])
print (b)
Counter({'is': 2, 'one': 1})

df = pd.DataFrame({'word':list(b.keys()),'count':list(b.values())}, columns=['word','count'])
print (df)
  word  count
0  one      1
1   is      2
```

Comment: can you check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45048818/keyword-search-between-two-dataframes-using-python-pandas